# Gradle Error: Colliding Attributes -- AndroidManifest.xml:38:17-38 is also present at [com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0]

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a Unity game as an .aab file for Android. The Unity project includes these two packages:

1. [Cross Platform Native Plugins](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/cross-platform-native-plugins-essential-kit-mobile-ios-android-140111)
2. [Firebase Crashlytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup).

However, when I try to build the .aab file, I keep getting this error:
[image]

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
/Users/kevinbunarjo/Desktop/joonity/Temp/gradleOut/launcher/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:38:17-38 Error:
    Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.versionCode@value value=(11003) from [:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:] AndroidManifest.xml:38:17-38
    is also present at [com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0] AndroidManifest.xml:17:85-106 value=(11000).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.versionCode@value value=(11003) from [:com.google.android.play.core-1.10.3:] AndroidManifest.xml:38:17-38
    is also present at [com.google.android.play:core:1.10.0] AndroidManifest.xml:17:85-106 value=(11000).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I've tried to do what it suggests and replace these two settings in the Android Manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

to:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

but I keep getting the same error.

I found this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407415/how-do-i-resolve-gradle-errorcolliding-attributes) that seems similar to mine, and tried using the most upvoted answer which says to delete the core-XXX.aar file in Assets/Plugins/Android, but I can't find the `core-1.10.0` file that my error is specifically is saying is the collision(the other answers didn't seem to make sense in my case since I don't have either x86 architectures checked).

Here are my project settings for what it's worth:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is with the core library versions used. Recent play core has artificts per feature compared to earlier library.

We(Voxel Busters) are already working on an update with rate library using the latest playcore which may avoid the issue.

We request to contact our support(discord) for the patch.

Comment: Got it! I'll reach out -- thank you!